# How to block seekbar in one direction

Tags: android, swipe, seekbar, direction

I would like to know if it is possible to block a seekbar in one direction ? (For example, once you have exceed a certain point you can't swipe right but only left. I don't want to change my max).

More details :
I have 7 seekbars and a variable which is named "totalProgress". 
When totalProgress=X, I would like to avoid seekbars to rise their progress (so swipe right) but I don't want to avoid them to reduce (swipe left).

edit : totalProgress is the sum of all progresses from my 7 seekbars.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
yourSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            int lastprogress = 0;

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                if(progress<lastprogress){
                    sb.setProgress(lastprogress);
                }else{
                    lastprogress = progress;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for your help !
I am not sure what you are trying to do : lastprogress is 0 by default so we go into the else for the first time. Then we will never go into the if  because lastprogress will always be equal to progress....

I have edited my question, just in case I was not clear ;)

Comment: If you try this code, you will see that you can't swipe left

Answer (score 0):

```
// mTotalProgress - outer variable with current total progress
// mMaxProgress - outer variable with allowable total progress

mSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new MySeekBarListener());

public class MySeekBarListener implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {

    private int mOthersProgress;

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        int totalProgress = mOthersProgress + progress;
        if (totalProgress > mMaxProgress) {
            int allowable = progress - (totalProgress - mMaxProgress);
            seekBar.setProgress(allowable);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        mOthersProgress = mTotalProgress - seekBar.getProgress();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        mTotalProgress = mOthersProgress + seekBar.getProgress();
    }
}
```